# AWS Amplify GraphQL Schema is causing an error

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I am new to Amplify and I am trying to set up a fairly complex schema. When I run amplify push, the only response that I get is ...

```
An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud
```

This happens after the notice that it will create the resources and I am asked if I want to continue. I deleted most of the schema and tried again with just one model and it worked, so there is a problem somewhere in my schema ... I guess? I don't see anywhere to check it.

Here is the schema

```
type Article
  @model
  @key(name: "bySource", fields: ["sourceId", "dateWritten"]) {
  id: ID!
  link: AWSURL!
  title: String!
  dateWritten: String!
  createdAt: String!
  data: AWSJSON!
  approved: Boolean!
  admin: Boolean!
  creatorId: ID!
  creator: User @connection(fields: ["creatorId"])
  sourceId: ID!
  source: Source @connection(fields: ["sourceId"])
  tagArtCons: [TagArtCon]
    @connection(keyName: "byArticle", fields: ["articleId"])
}

type Tag @model @key(name: "byFrontPage", fields: ["frontpage"]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  createdAt: String!
  creatorId: ID!
  data: AWSJSON!
  frontpage: String
  official: Boolean!
  tagArtConns: [TagArtCon] @connection(keyName: "byTag", fields: ["tagId"])
}

type TagArtCon
  @model
  @key(name: "byTag", fields: ["tagId"])
  @key(name: "byArticle", fields: ["articleId"]) {
  id: ID!
  tagId: ID!
  articleId: ID!
  creatorId: ID!
  createdAt: String!
  article: Article @connection(fields: ["articleId"])
  tag: Tag @connection(fields: ["tagId"])
  parentRelations: [TagRelation]
    @connection(keyName: "byParent", fields: ["tagId"])
  childRelations: [TagRelation]
    @connection(keyName: "byChild", fields: ["tagId"])
}

type TagRelation
  @model
  @key(name: "byParent", fields: ["parentId"])
  @key(name: "byChild", fields: ["childId"]) {
  id: ID!
  parentId: ID!
  childId: ID!
  creatorId: ID!
  createdAt: String!
  parentTag: Tag @connection(fields: ["parentId"])
  childTag: Tag @connection(fields: ["childId"])
}

type Source @model {
  id: ID!
  sourceName: String!
  sourceUrl: String!
  sourceImage: String!
  creatorId: ID!
  articles: [Article] @connection(keyName: "bySource", fields: ["id"])
}

type User @model {
  id: ID!
  userName: String!
  userImage: String!
  admin: Boolean!
  createdAt: String!
  data: AWSJSON
}
```

What I am trying to do is have a bunch of articles and a bunch of tags. The tags represent categories, people, etc. I have the following tables

articles,
tags,
a table where each entry ties an article to a tag
a table of relations between tags where parent/child relationships are held
a source table that just holds data for the sources of the articles
a user table

I've made a mistake somewhere and the schema isn't working and it isn't telling me why. I'm gonna keep simplifying this until I can hope to nail down the problem, but I would really appreciate any help as I am new to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the problem(s). There is a place where I try to use "articleId" and a place where I try to use "tagId" and both should be "id".